# Git, robots and diverging branches

Tags: database, git, branch

I am trying to use git as something it wasn't made for - a database. Please feel free to tell me that this is a stupid idea.

**Setup**

One branch (let's call it `robot`) is being updated automatically by a script on a daily basis. The data comes from some other publicly available database.

Initially the `master` branch is the same as the `robot` branch.

Some of the data in the publicly available database is wrong, so I'll make a commit to the `master` branch and correct the error.

When the script detects any changes on the public database in the future, it will add those to the `robot` branch as a new commit (there's one commit per file).

**Keeping track of differences**

Now, I've obviously lost the ability to do a fast forward merge if I've modified the same file. But I could still cherry pick the good changes in the `robot` branch and import them into the `master` branch. The problem is that this might get rather messy after a while, when almost all the files have diverged.

How can I keep track of the difference between the different branches in a systematic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command. This command allows you to update changes you've made to your `master` branch on top of the new head of the `robot` branch:

```
git checkout master
git rebase robot
```

There may be conflicts, if the database has been updated with a change to something you've changed in `master`. You must resolve those conflicts manually.

Comment: The only problem is that people wont like it when I do this on a remote branch.